# PDO: How to send an ajax serialized data to a php controller?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I make a ajax call that is triggered when a checkbox is checked or unchecked. I am new to PDO mvc design. What I am attempting to do is when the ajax call is made the serialized data is passed to an object which calls a functions that sets this data in the DB.

ajax:

```
$('#interests').on('change', 'input', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var str = $('#interests').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'index.php',
    async:  true,
    traditional: true,
    data: str,
    success:  function (msg) {
      console.log(msg);

    }
  });
});
```

Interest controller:

```
class InterestController
{

  function __construct(){}
  public function set_user_interest()
  {
    $table='interests';
    $_POST['Username']=$_SESSION['logname'];

    $interest = new Interests($_POST, $table);

    if ($interest->set_interest()) {
      echo "interest were set";
    }
    else {
      echo "something went wrong with interest";
    }
    # code...
  }
```

All controllers are usually created by a routes file, which based on the string passed to the url constructs that object.

routes:

```
<?php
function call($controller, $action){
  require_once('controllers/' . $controller . '_controller.php');

    // create a new instance of the needed controller
    switch($controller) {
      case 'landing':
        $controller = new LandingController();
        break;
      case 'login':
        $controller = new LoginController();
        break;
      case 'signup_form':
        $controller = new SignupFormController();
        break;
      case 'signup':
        require_once 'models/users.php';
        require_once 'models/interest.php';
        $controller = new SignupController();
        break;
      case 'interest':
        require_once 'models/interest.php';
        $controller = new InterestController();
    }

    // call the action
    $controller->{ $action }();
}
// just a list of the controllers we have and their actions
// we consider those "allowed" values
$controllers = array('landing'=>['landing_page', 'error'],
                      'signup_form'=>['set_signup_form', 'error'],
                      'signup'=>['create_user', 'error'],
                      'interest'=>['set_user_interest', 'error']
                    );

// check that the requested controller and action are both allowed
// if someone tries to access something else he will be redirected to the error action of the pages controller
if (array_key_exists($controller, $controllers)) {
  if (in_array($action, $controllers[$controller])) {
    call($controller, $action);
  } else {
    call('landing', 'error');
  }
} else {
  call('landing', 'error');
}

 ?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('Water.inc');
if (isset($_GET['controller']) && isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $controller = $_GET['controller'];
    $action     = $_GET['action'];
  } else {
    $controller = 'landing';
    $action     = 'landing_page';
  }

require_once 'views/layout.php';
 ?>
```

How would i send a serialized form to a controller that sends it to the database, using ajax?

Comment: SO what is the exact question?

Comment: Has nothing todo with pdo or mysql

Comment: Serialized data is sent in `data` parameter of `ajax` call. So now go to `index.php` and `print_r($_POST)` there.

Comment: @u_mulder i understand that but it 'print_r' wouldnt be called in the background right?  index.php is just a file that reads query strings and calls the appropriate action. I am editing and posting that file now.

Comment: @Kevlwig it will be called for sure, but the results will not show in screen. instead, it will be part of the response body of your ajax call, you're able to see this response using your browser developer tools

Comment: also, you seem to not be using your routes at all, since you're calling a file directly (index.php)

Comment: @leo_ap i can pass a string within the url of the ajax call correct? Like `index.php?controller=interest&action=set_user_interest`?

Comment: yes, you can. But you should try to avoid this kind of routing control. try redirecting all requests to index.php, and there, you parse the url (like www.yoursite.com/interest/set) and redirects to correct controller

Answer (score 0):

Select Country
    ">
     
       Select State
        
    
                 Select City

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#COUNTRIES").change(function(){
    var CID =  $('#COUNTRIES').val();
    $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'<?php echo base_url('index.php/Userc/SERVICE2') ?>',
            data: {"CID":CID},
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(result){                                      
                $('#STATES').html(result); },                                       
            });     
        });
```

//*********************controller******************//

```
public function SERVICE2(){

    if ($this->input->post('CID')) {
            $CID = $this->input->post('CID');
               $where = array('CID' => $CID);
                $query['P'] = $this->Model1->displaywhere('states',$where);
                        $html = '<option>Select State</option>';
                        foreach($query['P'] as $row) {  

    $html .="<option value=".$row['SID'].">".$row['SNAME']."</option>";}
            echo json_encode($html); // must..}
```